# Adding a DateTime object to a List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, datetimecontrol

I'm quite nice to Sharepoint so pardon my lack of knowledge.

In my web part design, I am using this to obtain date and time from the user:

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="interviewSlot" runat="server" />
```

So I am trying to add the DateTime object from interviewSlot into a particular Item in my "Application" list here:

```
objJobApplicants = objCurrentWeb.Lists["Application"];
foreach (SPListItem objApplicantItem in objJobApplicants.Items)
{
     if (objApplicantItem["ApplicantName"].ToString().Equals(applicant))
     {
         objApplicantItem["InterviewTimeslot"] = interviewSlot.SelectedDate;
     }
}
```

InterviewTimeslot is a of a Date and Time data type in the list.

The code seems to run fine, however the selected date in the web part is not being added to the Application list. Am I missing some step that is needed specifically for a DateTime object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you posted, looks like you need to call Update() on the item:

```
if (objApplicantItem["ApplicantName"].ToString().Equals(applicant))
{
    objApplicantItem["InterviewTimeslot"] = interviewSlot.SelectedDate;
    objApplicantItem.Update();
}
```

[SPListItem.Update method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.update%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: If you are new to SharePoint, you should make yourself familiar with the Update() method.  Many, many objects in the SharePoint object model have this method, and what it does is write the changes you make to an object into the database so that the changes persist.